# fetch/axios async/await request freeze app in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, asynchronous, async-await, fetch

I have some problem in my app when request API. My problem is the following:

When app request is awaiting, the app is totally freeze and the clicking event on the setting tab or test 2 button will be only triggered when the request is done. If anyone got the same issue and find a way to handle it
Please answer, thank you!

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isLoading: false
  }

  fetchData = () => {
    console.log('1');
    this.setState({isLoading:true});

    // await Promise.all(
      data.map(async (x) => {  
        await axios.get(x.url);        
      })
    // )

    console.log('2');    
    this.setState({isLoading:false})
  }

  renderLoading = () => {     
    if (this.state.isLoading) { 
      return <ActivityIndicator size={40} />
    }
    return null
  }

  test2 = () => {
    console.log('3');   
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'flex-end', alignItems: 'center' }}>             
        {this.renderLoading()}
        <TouchableOpacity style={{height: 50}} onPress={() => this.fetchData()}><Text>Test</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={{height: 50}} onPress={() => this.test2()}><Text>Test 2</Text></TouchableOpacity>            
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: where is `data` defined?

Comment: Are you running on the device? If so, what happens when you disable remote debugging? Also, how many elements are in `data`?

Comment: is `console.log(2)` output almost immediately after `console.log(1)` (it would be)

Comment: @Bravo yes, but when i press "test 2" button doesn't show immediately log(3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I found solution using next-frame:

```
let queue = Promise.resolve();       
data.forEach(x => {
    queue = queue.then(() => nextFrame().then(async () => {
        const response = await fetch(x.url);
        const content = await response.text();
        console.log(content);
    }));
});
queue.then(() => {
    console.log('complete!');    
    this.setState({isLoading:false})
});
```